Determine consecutive increase for every 3 rows for multiple columns in a dataframe
My data consists of the moving averages of weekly cases for multiple districts. Below is a short example of the whole dataset which has over 100 columns and 500 rows
   State A   State B    State C    State D
1   9.5       64.5      10.0       5.5 
2  28.0       64.0       6.0       3.0
3  38.5      104.5      17.0       4.5
4  20.5      118.0      23.0       5.0
5  10.5       99.5      17.0       5.0
6   7.5       78.0      14.0       3.0
7  12.0       73.0      20.5       2.5
8  17.5       74.5      20.0       2.0
9  19.0       69.0      12.5       5.0
10 14.5       64.5      15.0       7.0

I'd like to determine an outbreak by consecutive increase for every 3 rows which will be labeled TRUE or FALSE. This should be applied to all columns.
Each row will be labeled 'TRUE' only if it is bigger than the previous row AND the previous row is bigger the the row before it.
So technically, if x[i]>x[i-1] & x[i-1]>x[i-2] is true, then x[i] should be labeled TRUE, and false otherwise.
The result should be like this:
   State A   State B    State C    State D
1  FALSE     FALSE      FALSE      FALSE 
2  FALSE     FALSE      FALSE      FALSE
3  TRUE      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE
4  FALSE     TRUE       TRUE       TRUE
5  FALSE     FALSE      FALSE      FALSE
6  FALSE     FALSE      FALSE      FALSE
7  FALSE     FALSE      FALSE      FALSE
8  TRUE      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE
9  TRUE      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE
10 FALSE     FALSE      FALSE      TRUE

I have tried using the following code:
for (i in 3:nrow(data)) {
    # Check for positive increase in each preceding row
    if (data[i] > data[i - 1] & data[i - 1] > data[i - 2]) {
      data[i] <- "TRUE"
    }
  else{data[i] <- "FALSE"}
  }

but it gives me an error:

Error in if (test[i] > test[i - 1] & test[i - 1] > test[i - 2]) { :
the condition has length > 1

There is also another code by my teammate but it does not determine the outbreak correctly:
checkfun <- function(x) {
  c(F,F,head(diff(x)>0,-1)&tail(diff(x)>0,-1))
}
outbreak=data.frame(sapply(na.omit(data),checkfun))


as a side note for the next question you may be asking: adding a reproducible example helps and replying is faster :-) see here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Your team mate's code works for your toy data.

1) Create a function all.diff which differences its vector argument and then returns TRUE if all the elements are TRUE and FALSE otherwise.  Then use rollapplyr with a width of 3 to apply it to each column of data.
If it were desired to examine stretches of 4 (or other value) instead of 3 just change 3 to 4 (or other value).
library(zoo)

all.diff <- function(x) all(diff(x) > 0)
rollapplyr(data, 3, all.diff, fill = FALSE)

giving this matrix.  (Since it is entirely logical a matrix seems to make the most sense but if you want a data frame use as.data.frame on it.)
      State A State B State C State D
 [1,]   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
 [2,]   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
 [3,]    TRUE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
 [4,]   FALSE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
 [5,]   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
 [6,]   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
 [7,]   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
 [8,]    TRUE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
 [9,]    TRUE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
[10,]   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE    TRUE

2) Alternately we can fix the code in the question by first creating a data frame, outdata of all FALSE values and then filling it in row by row:
outdata <- replace(data, TRUE, FALSE)
for (i in 3:nrow(data)) {
  outdata[i, ] <- data[i, ] > data[i - 1, ] & data[i - 1, ] > data[i - 2, ]
}

2a) Note that we can omit the for loop by defining a vector of indices, ix, like this:
outdata <- replace(data, TRUE, FALSE)
ix <- 3:nrow(data)
outdata[ix, ] <- data[ix, ] > data[ix - 1, ] & data[ix - 1, ] > data[ix - 2, ]

Note
Input in reproducible form:
data <- data.frame(
  `State A` = c(9.5, 28, 38.5, 20.5, 10.5, 7.5, 12, 17.5, 19, 14.5),
  `State B` = c(64.5, 64, 104.5, 118, 99.5, 78, 73, 74.5, 69, 64.5),
  `State C` = c(10, 6, 17, 23, 17, 14, 20.5, 20, 12.5, 15),
  `State D` = c(5.5, 3, 4.5, 5, 5, 3, 2.5, 2, 5, 7),
  check.names = FALSE
)


Added solution (2a).

We can use sapply to go through the rows in your dataframe.
If the row index is smaller than 3, assign FALSE (that equals the number of columns in the original dataframe), otherwise, check if your conditions were met. Finally, rename the results with original column names.
sapply(1:nrow(df), \(x) {
  if (x < 3) rep(F, ncol(df)) else (df[x, ] > df[x - 1, ]) & (df[x - 1, ] > df[x - 2, ])
}) |> 
  t() |> 
  as.data.frame() |> 
  setNames(colnames(df))

   StateA StateB StateC StateD
1   FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
2   FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
3    TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
4   FALSE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE
5   FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
6   FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
7   FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
8    TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
9    TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
10  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE


The results differ from the expected output

@Onyambu Thanks for the comment, removed some unnecessary codes that messed up.

A tidyverse approach:
pivot_longer(df, -week, names_to="State") |>
  mutate(outbreak=week>2 & value>lag(value) & lag(value)>lag(value, 2), .by=State) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from=State, values_from=c(value, outbreak)) |>
  select(week, starts_with("outbreak"))

# A tibble: 10 x 5
    week outbreak_A outbreak_B outbreak_C outbreak_D
   <dbl> <lgl>      <lgl>      <lgl>      <lgl>     
 1     1 FALSE      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE     
 2     2 FALSE      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE     
 3     3 TRUE       FALSE      FALSE      FALSE     
 4     4 FALSE      TRUE       TRUE       TRUE      
 5     5 FALSE      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE     
 6     6 FALSE      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE     
 7     7 FALSE      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE     
 8     8 TRUE       FALSE      FALSE      FALSE     
 9     9 TRUE       FALSE      FALSE      FALSE     
10    10 FALSE      FALSE      FALSE      TRUE 


df <- structure(list(week = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), A = c(9.5, 
28, 38.5, 20.5, 10.5, 7.5, 12, 17.5, 19, 14.5), B = c(64.5, 64, 
104.5, 118, 99.5, 78, 73, 74.5, 69, 64.5), C = c(10, 6, 17, 23, 
17, 14, 20.5, 20, 12.5, 15), D = c(5.5, 3, 4.5, 5, 5, 3, 2.5, 
2, 5, 7)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))


the problem is that you forgot to go through the columns (a matrix, or a dataframe has columns and rows).
your check, using only data[i - 1] is not working because data is not a vector. here you're using it as a vector, but it is, in fact, a matrix with rows and columns.
this solution follows your approach, but i added the columns, too:
# create a dataframe as the one you copy pasted
data <- cbind.data.frame(stateA=c(9.5, 28, 38.5, 20.5, 10.5, 7.5, 12, 17.5, 19, 14.5), stateB=c(64.5, 64, 104.5, 118, 99.5, 78, 73, 74.5, 69, 64.5), stateC=c(10, 6, 17, 23, 17, 14, 20.5, 20, 12.5, 15), stateD=c(5.5, 3, 4.5, 5, 5, 3, 2.5, 2, 5, 7))

# create a final table (a matrix) with the results
# i assume all as false, until proven true
# since the first two rows are always false
data_checked <- matrix(ncol=ncol(data), nrow=nrow(data), FALSE)

# loop through columns
for (j in 1:ncol(data)) {
    # loop through rows
    for (i in 3:nrow(data)) {
        # Check for positive increase in each preceding row
        if (data[i, j] > data[i - 1, j] & data[i - 1, j] > data[i - 2, j]) {
            # add true in position (i, j)
            data_checked[i, j] <- TRUE
        }
        else{
            # add false in position (i, j)
            data_checked[i, j] <- FALSE
        }
    }
}
# convert matrix to dataframe if needed
data_checked <- as.data.frame(data_checked)
# add colnames to easy access as defined for data
colnames(data_checked) <- colnames(data)


library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df |>
  mutate(across(starts_with("State"), \(x) replace_na(x > lag(x) & lag(x) > lag(x, 2), F)))
#    State_A State_B State_C State_D
# 1    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
# 2    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
# 3     TRUE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
# 4    FALSE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
# 5    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
# 6    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
# 7    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
# 8     TRUE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
# 9     TRUE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
# 10   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE    TRUE

